# Solving a logarithmic equation: got two answers but one is rejected. Why?

Tags: logarithms

[image]

[image]

the answer in the textbook is 10^[1-√(3)]/2.
how does the other root not satisfy the original equation?

Comment: 10^{1+root3}/2 = 23.228 & 10^{1-root3}/2 = 1/10^(0.36002) = 0.43050 both values of x i got are +ve

Comment: It seems to me that your solutions are correct. Plot the function : it will confirm your results.

Comment: Performing the calculation with $x = 10^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}}$ shows (unless I made an error in my computation...) that the "other" solution is indeed correct also. Is there anything else mentioned in your book that would invalidate it ? otherwise I'd say it's valid.

Comment: although the book pretty much gave just one answer with no explanation, i think both solutions are correct.